# Dog red area around pyometra suture

Tags: dogs

My Dog had a pyometra surgery in middle of September and she has been on the road to recovery - her activity levels are normal now (touchwood) and she is eating food normally. But over the last week or so we noticed a suture reaction and took her to the vet. This is how it looks:
[image]

The vet prescribed antibiotic and on Monday this is how it looked: It was healing well -

[image]

We still continued the antibiotic till it course is about to end - but now that area looks like this:

[image]

What is that area? The emergency vet says that since it is far away from the suture area might be just that the skin might having something going wrong there. Or is it just a suture reaction? Isn't a suture supposed to be dissolved by now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE :) I hope you will find an answer to your question soon. It is a very good documented, good style question!

Comment: Surtures that don't dissolve usually cause a blood red blister, not a ring. I'm not a vet and can only speculate, but from your description it sounds like a mild infection or at least irritation of the skin.